# options for slow cassandra write

Tags: cassandra, streaming

I'm ingesting very large files into Cassandra 2.0 and I'm noticing that my ingest rate into Cassandra will be x3 slower than the rate at which I'm getting new files to ingest.  Given that, and trying to avoid memory problems, what are my options for keeping up with ingest?

I was initially thinking that I could have multiple clients writing, possibly each to a different "seed" node in the cluster.  If I am careful about not accessing the same file twice will that cause problems with the node I/O?  What is the best way to go about doing this?  Based on google searches I have seen things like batch driver statements can help, but I'm reading in CSV files which need to be cleaned first...

Comment: If you want to write the data using a normal client (thrift/CQL) then multiple clients is a good idea, ideally on separate machines - it's essentially impossible to saturate a cassandra cluster using only a single write client.

Comment: What's your consistency level for these writes?

Comment: Also, what's your topology?